# Angular.js 'Unknown provider: iProvider <- i' error in production

Tags: javascript, angularjs, divshot

I am working on an Angular Project, on local it runs perfectly, but when I deploy to Divshot it breaks, and it throws an 'Unknown provider: iProvider <- i' error.

This is the link to the: [Divshot development build](http://development.valanti.divshot.io/)

Any advice will be very appreciated.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem.  I was minifying my js, and using ngAnnotate to make the code safe for minification.  However, ngAnnotate only recognizes a certain number of patterns, and if you create a pattern where you expect injection to occur which ngAnnotate doesn't recognize, you have to tell it to handle the injection via @ngInject.  Not sure if that is your problem, but it might help.

Answer (score 3):

It is because Angular resolves the provider names by literally converting a function into string and using its parameter names. When you deploy, you are probably minifying your code. Therefore something that looked like `myCoolService` will be minified to `i` or `a` or something else.

You have to ways to solve it:
1. Use array syntax
2. Use ngAnnotate or something else in your build to create the array syntax for you.

Read the part about Minification on https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

Comment: Thanks @AlexStack, that was the problem indeed.

Comment: Great! :) I appreciate if you can mark my answer as the correct one so that I can get the points.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your js code has been minifized in production. The identifier of your service provider might be renamed to something unknown.

I'd suggest your add a string identifier of your provider at injection point. E.g.

```
angular.module('example')
  .controller(['$scope', 'YourServiceProvider', function($scope, YourServiceProvider) {
     // ...
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @stanleyxu2005!